# Extracting Lat/Long values from multiple files and outputs to New File

Tags: perl

```
[Users:~/Desktop/cross_correlated]$cat 20131102.18582702.mcp 
MCCC processed: unknown event at: Thu, 16 Oct 2014 11:09:42 CST 
station, mccc delay,    std,    cc coeff,  cc std,   pol   , t0_times  , delay_times
 ZJ.sta1     -0.0374    0.0015    0.9851    0.0098    0  APRL.BHZ   301.7639    -0.1217
 ZJ.sta2     -0.0545    0.0015    0.9907    0.0101    0  BEBP.BHZ   301.9218    -0.2967
 ZJ.sta3      0.4622    0.0015    0.9724    0.0126    0  CASY.BHZ   301.6886     0.4533
 ZJ.sta4      0.2697    0.0081    0.9819    0.0146    0  DONT.BHZ   300.7176     1.2318
 ZJ.sta5     -0.3824    0.0058    0.9805    0.0160    0  DUBY.BHZ   302.1706    -0.8733
 ZJ.sta6      0.2499    0.0015    0.9873    0.0139    0  FOOT.BHZ   302.1762    -0.2467
 ZJ.sta7     -0.5377    0.0015    0.9813    0.0132    0  GRAW.BHZ   301.8386    -0.6967
 ZJ.sta8     -0.5245    0.0015    0.9546    0.0118    0  KNYN.BHZ   302.2768    -1.1217
 ZJ.sta9      0.6591    0.0081    0.9875    0.0089    0  LEON.BHZ   302.0388     0.3000
 ZJ.staa      0.4446    0.0015    0.9878    0.0089    0  MICH.BHZ   301.5210     0.6033
 ZJ.RAPH      0.3358    0.0015    0.9891    0.0121    0  RAPH.BHZ   301.4371     0.5783
 ZJ.RKST     -0.5451    0.0015    0.9886    0.0123    0  RKST.BHZ   301.5813    -0.4467
 ZJ.xzzz     -0.6739    0.0058    0.9912    0.0100    0  SAMH.BHZ   301.9008    -0.8950
 ZJ.xyzz      0.2476    0.0015    0.9898    0.0098    0  SHRD.BHZ   302.2989    -0.3717
 ZJ.xzzz      0.0866    0.0015    0.9862    0.0114    0  SPLN.BHZ   301.7630     0.0033
Mean_arrival_time:   301.6797 
No weighting of equations. 
Window:   3.12   Inset:   1.43  Shift:   0.25 
Variance: 0.00373   Coefficient: 0.98360  Sample rate:   40.000 
Taper:   0.39 
Phase: P        
PDE    2013 11  2 18 58 27.02   **-19.171  -172.641**   10.1  0.0  6.2
```

I have multiple files with the format specified above in one directory.
I need to create a script, that takes the Lat/Long values that I've highlighted above, in the PDE row, for each file, and exports them into a two column text file.

How would I do this in perl?  I am new to Perl, but if there was a sort of template to follow, that would be helpful.  Preferably, I want to write a perl script that finds the PDE line, counts over to the 7th and 8th space, and extracts those values.  Do I need to specify the new file name in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -lane 'print "@F[7,8]" if /^PDE/' 20131102.18582702.mcp
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/ORsQDN)</kbd>

#### Using a Script instead

To use a script, the following will create equivalent logic.

Note: if you want to process multiple files, you can use the commented out line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV = ('20131102.18582702.mcp');
# @ARGV = glob('*.mcp');

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split ' ';

    print "@F[7,8]\n" if /^PDE/;
}
```

Comment: If I want to use this code, with multiple *.mcp files in some Directory, should I do:

    perl -lane 'print "@F[7,8]" if /^PDE/' *.mcp

Comment: Correct, if you're on a system that enables shell * expansion, then that will work.

Comment: OK, so in your demo, you note that <DATA> is one file.  Should I create a list of each file name and use that for <DATA> so that the while loop knows to loop through each file?

Comment: `DATA` is a special file handle I used to include data in the live demo.  You will need to use a different method to process multiple external files, like I just added.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -l -n -a -e '$F[0] eq "PDE" && print $F[7], "\t", $F[8]' *.mcp
```

Using `awk` may be simpler:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 == "PDE" { print $8, $9 }' *.mcp
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

```
awk '/^PDE/{print $8,$9}' *.mcp
```

That says... on all lines that start with `PDE`, print the 8th and 9th fields, using the default delimiter of one or more spaces to separate fields, and do this for all files that have the extension `.mcp`.

Comment: If you are going to down-vote, it would be courteous to explain why.

Comment: I didn't downvote... but it would be more useful with some explanation of the expression. It is very unlikely that any further reader have the exact same problem... as it is now: this answer is only useful to the OP.

Comment: @ben75 I take your point and have added a little explanation. Thank you.